# Accidentlly removed pyconfig.h file from /usr/include/python2.7 on Debian Squeeze

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, installation, debian

I stumbled upon a problem that I can't solve in the past 2 hours, and I would be very grateful if you could help me.

I accidently removed the file *pyconfig.h* from **/usr/include/python2.7** and now my python2.7 version doesn't work. I tried the following steps:

1. Tried to find the *pyconfig.h* file on the net and simple place it in **/usr/include/python2.7** but I couldn't find this file.
2. Tried to find a way to re-install Python 2.7
3. Tried to remove Python 2.7 and install it again

Can you help me solve this problem? I am on debian squeeze and linux beginner.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving the dependency issue should be the best way for you to fix this.

But you could always download the package from [debian](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python2.7-minimal) and unpack the deb and get the file like this:

```
wget http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-minimal_2.7.3~rc2-2.1_amd64.deb
ar -x python2.7-minimal_2.7.3~rc2-2.1_amd64.deb
tar -xzf data.tar.gz
sudo cp usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h
```

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalling the package is indeed the simplest solution. On [Debian's website](http://packages.debian.org) you can find out which package it is in. In this case it seems to be [python2.7-minimal](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=pyconfig.h&mode=path&suite=unstable&arch=any). Reinstall that package and all should be fine again.

Comment: Oh, I looked for pyconfig.h instead of pyconf.h, but I think that was exactly what you needed to do. That file exists, while pyconf.h doesn't.

Comment: Well, I tried to reinstal the package, but it gives me an error:
Dependency is not satisfiable: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.3-5)
What should I do?

Comment: BTW, thanks for the correction about the name of the file, I've edited my post.

Comment: Which package did you try to reinstall? You should be reinstalling python2.7-minimal. Which package complains about this dependency?

Comment: OK, I was installing the 2.7 package, not the minimal.
But, when I tried installing the minimal package, the one from here: http://packages.debian.org/sid/python2.7-minimal
it also gave me a similar error:
Breaks existing package 'python2.7' dependency python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.3~rc2-2.1)
I think there is some conflict between the version that is already installed. 
Any ideas what else to try?

Comment: I don't know what version of Debian you are using (testing, I'm guessing?), but you should almost never install files you download from the internet other than by using a package manager. Your system should be able to find a version which works with the rest of your system. So just use aptitude or synaptic to select the package and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Bas Wijnen, but @Arnestig solved my problem (you can see his answer). The solution is: download the package from debian and unpack the deb and get the file. Thanks again for your answers.

Comment: It solves the issue, but read his first line: it isn't the proper way to fix it. If you want a stable system, Debian is a very good choice. But you shouldn't mess with its files, and if you do, the best way to fix it is by letting the system take care of it. Debian maintainers have put effort into making sure that things work. Trust them and let their scripts handle things. It will result in a more stable system for you. Your own things belong in /etc (for configuration), /usr/local (for locally installed packages) or /home/$USER (for per-user stuff).

Comment: I am aware of that, but I tried a lot of packages and none of them worked, so I had to do it this way.